# Why is my movement always active?

Tags: c++, sdl2

I can't quite figure this out, no matter the various modifications I make.

What *should* happen: I want this to only move the player on left click/left up if i have previously right clicked

What actually happens: Regardless of which mouse button I click/unclick, it activates the direction function.

The offending code:

```
class Controller_Mouse : public Component
{
public:

    Component_Transform *transform;

    void init() override
    {
        transform = &entity->get_component<Component_Transform>();
    }

    void update() override
    {
        if (Game::event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN)
        {
            if (SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT)
            {
                transform->active = true;
            }

            if (SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
            {
                if (transform->active == true)
                {
                    std::cout << "transform vals: " << transform->position.x << ", " << transform->position.y << std::endl;
                    std::cout << "click vals:     " << Game::event.motion.x << ", " << Game::event.motion.y << std::endl;

                    transform->target.x = Game::event.motion.x; transform->target.y = Game::event.motion.y;
                }

                transform->active = false;
            }
        }
        if (Game::event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP && SDL_BUTTON_LEFT)
        {
            transform->direction(transform->position.x, transform->position.y, transform->target.x, transform->target.y);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4):

You are not comparing anything to the mouse constants in your if-statements. You need to include the event's mouse button member there.

Comment: No, not the solution.

Comment: @Chris You are checking if(SDL_BUTTON_RIGHT) and right after if(SDL_BUTTON_LEFT). These will always evaluate to true.

Comment: There's also a lonely constant in the last if.

Comment: @Chris: Just saying "no" doesn't give users much information to be able to help you. What specific changes did you try to make, and what outcomes did you observe? This info can help narrow in on what's going wrong.